# Ways to reduce supply chain risks for java apps

Tags: java

What are the best practices for supply chain risks reduction for java applications? In my opinion java dependency management has the following downsides:

- Java applications use 3rd party dependencies and compiled jar files are usually downloaded from artifactory (in compliled form, not like source code);
- Although jar files can be signed almost no one adopted signature checks; I haven't seen any build system that checks signatures by default and breaks builds in case of mismatch;
- Developers can add dependencies just listing them in project files (for example, pom.xml) and they'll be resolved and downloaded during build;
- Almost anyone can add jar library to an artifactory;

Are there any good approaches to cope with the downsides above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one defend against software supply chain attacks?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/243575/how-does-one-defend-against-software-supply-chain-attacks)

Comment: My question is only about java, the question you mentioned is about general case and the answer is "impossible" is not the one I'm looking for

Comment: Just because it's not the answer you're looking for doesn't mean it's not the correct one.

Comment: "Impossible" in general case doesn't mean that there's no solution for a more narrowed case.

Comment: To your first point... executable jar files are human readable.  (unless an obfuscator is used...)  You can just extract the file.  It contains the classes and a manifest that tell the run-time what the main method is.

Comment: They can be decompiled but usually you lose class and variables names so it requires efforts to understand the logic

Answer (score 1):

Like I mentioned in my comment, supply chain risks can't be completely eliminated. [This question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/243575/how-does-one-defend-against-software-supply-chain-attacks), which I also linked to, explains it rather well.

Let's have a look at each specific point of concern:

#### Dependencies are downloaded as already compiled code.

This could be because the dependency is some proprietary code and source code is not available, or simply out of convenience.

You could either decompile and reverse engineer what the dependency does, or analyze the source code if available. The problem is, nobody does that. It's thousands of lines of code - your developers already have an enormous codebase to deal with, so asking them to basically learn a whole new codebase *for every dependency* will get people to question the sanity of whoever ordered that. In other words: Analyzing the source code for every dependency, just to ensure it doesn't contain any bugs or backdoors, will bring development to a standstill. And then you have to assume that programmers will spot the backdoor. Just for fun, here's a backdoor:

```
if ((options == (__WCLONE|__WALL)) && (current->uid = 0))
        retval = -EINVAL;
```

Try finding it. Keep in mind that this is 2 lines and you know there is a backdoor. Now imagine playing the same game with thousands of lines of code, and not knowing if there is one.

#### Problems with Jar Signatures

The fact that signatures are not checked by default is a feature. Requiring every Jar to be signed is not something that most developers care about - still only takes a handful of flags to enable that, so that's not the issue.

Problems arise only when developers of some library you want to use don't sign their Jars. Either use a different library or ask the developer to sign their Jars. However, even signed Jars don't stop an attacker from inserting a backdoor into the source code, depending on how well the signing practices of the developer are.

In essence, signing jars *can* help, but it's not the be-all-end-all of supply chain attacks. And against a malicious developer, it doesn't protect at all.

#### Developers can add arbitrary dependencies

Yeah, the point of build systems is to be easy to use and add as little friction as possible. That means developers are encouraged by the system to just add what they need.

Now, a responsible developer would consider the downsides of adding a new dependency to a project, weigh in whether this would be a reasonable thing to do or not, and then check how trustworthy the library and its developer is.

A less responsible developer just adds a library that sounds kind-of like it does what they need it to do, and then just see if it works. All an attacker needs to do is create a package named `html-parser` or `json` and tons of people will fly to it.

### In summary...

nothing you can really do in practice. You can do the things suggested in the linked answer, such as running separate environments, doing code audits for specific versions, etc.. Aside from that, you just have to trust.

Comment: `Try finding it` - it's relatively easy to spot as it looks like someone mistyped "=" instead of "==" :)


`However, even signed Jars don't stop an attacker from inserting a backdoor into the source code, depending on how well the signing practices of the developer are` - signing is not a silver bullet, it's just a way to protect jars from hacked artifactory. Similar expample - DockerHub was compromised some time ago and checking signatures of docker images could help to ensure their integrity.

Comment: @CaptainRR Now try finding the backdoor [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html)